# Call any Java method from C#

Tags: c#, java, interop, java-native-interface

Is there a way using JNI and C# code to create a program that invoke any given Java method?
Assume that I have a jar containing classes hierarchy and I'm responsible for loading the JVM and these classes, can I write a C# program that receives the java method signature + arguments values on the fly and call the java code?

Please try to restrict your answers to free technologies (JNI solutions prefered).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/) is one option. It implements a JVM in .Net and provides interop tools.

Comment: How can IKVM helps here, the resolution should be made in runtime and not by creating static artifacts (.NET proxies)?

Comment: @Guy - IKVM can be used in both dynamic and static modes; see http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ikvm/index.php?title=User%27s_Guide  In dynamic mode, Java bytecodes are translated on the fly into CIL by the class loader.

Comment: Being more general, I want to draw away from the solution that creates .NET proxy.

Comment: The dynamic mode is just as calling Java.exe and can be applied on java programs (i.e. with main(String[]) ). Not good for me.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO the best way would be to run the Java Program as a WebService (or create a Java based WebService Interface for it) and just call it from C#.

Comment: I didn't mention that I don't have any clue regarding the Java code nor any possibility to change it. The only input I have is:
JAR, method name, arguments and values

Comment: dbenerlin : What are complex data types supported in Java which are supported in .Net ? Thx